# Apple Watch Unhackable without iPhone?

Tags: malware, attack-prevention, iphone

In response to the UK banning Apple Watch from cabinet meetings, this [article](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3128863/apple-ios/uk-government-apple-watch-ban-achieves-nothing.html) implies that the Apple Watch is essentially harmless (unhackable) with the paired iPhone inaccessible. This seems ridiculous, since the watch has GPS, Microphone, Bluetooth, and Wi-Fi capabilities. I would expect that a hack could occur before, during, or after a meeting and retrieve information exposed regardless of the paired phone's status. I'm going from statements made by Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204562).

Is there something I'm missing with the iPhone pairing? Is there any legitimacy to the assertions in the linked article?

Relevant quote:
"*This means that no one can hack into the Watch once the phone is offline, which itself means all the UK government needs to do is switch its smartphones off. It’s a typical misstep. Though it does make sense to keep all the electronics offline during a critical meeting, I guess.*"

Comment: Its Apple,  after the fappaning, i don't think anyone should trust them.  Clearly they have faults in their secure software development life cycle.

Comment: It would be easier and better to ban iDevices than iWatches

Comment: @rook Better abandon Microsoft and anyone else who ever had a user's account compromised while you are at it. Clearly they have faults too.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara there are faults, and then there is shipping software with known issues.  Apple was burned by brute force multiple times, and I know for a fact that apple ignores the advice from their overwhelmed security team.  If Apple cared, then they would have a bug bounty program like Google and Microsoft.  "The Fappening 5" is just a release or two away.

Comment: @rook You might want to do some research on that, as Apple *does* have a bug bounty program, even though they feel they cannot outbid the massive payouts black hats are getting compared to their competitors. Also, I think a lack of rate limiting is more a lack of threat mitigation, than an actual vulnerability. Besides, users using bad passwords has no direct or perfect technical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iWatch, like most computer equipment, is designed to be secure. However, **vulnerabilities** can arise which mean it doesn't really deliver the security it is supposed to. The vulnerabilities could be design weaknesses (e.g. poor encryption), coding weaknesses (e.g. buffer overruns), user error (e.g. weak passwords) and much more.

An iWatch is a computer. If it is hacked, it can be programmed to do whatever the attacker wants. It could record all the audio - even if offline - then next time it is connected to the Internet, it uploads the audio to the attacker's server.

As far as I know, there are no public exploits against the iWatch ([this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3081478/Apple-Watch-security-flaw-leaves-vulnerable-thieves-Device-reset-paired-phone-minutes.html) doesn't count). But who knows what attacks have been discovered in secret? There are plenty of people trying to create malware like [this](http://www.middleeasteye.net/news/israel-uae-us-spyware-ahmed-mansoor-773014960).

The cabinet is more-or-less the most confidential meeting that happens in the UK. They are certainly a target for sophisticated espionage attacks, so banning iWatches makes complete sense. The article you reference is not credible.